Need assistance in python3 code getting error message
The purpose of my code is to sole the Friedmann equation by numerically integrating for a given pair of Omega_M,0 and Omega_Lambda,0. This is my code below and I need help figuring out how to fix my error in my code. This is what I get when I try to run my code.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shakeila/project.py", line 30, in <module>
    a_values, H_values = solve_friedmann(Omega_M0, Omega_Lambda0)
  File "/home/shakeila/project.py", line 18, in solve_friedmann
    result, _ = quad(integrand, 0, a, args=(Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 351, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: integrand() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I try taking out the args= part in my code but I get the same type of error.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Constants
H0 = 70.0  # Hubble constant in km/s/Mpc
Omega_r0 = 0.0  # Radiation density parameter (ignored)

# Function to integrate
def integrand(Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    return 1.0 / np.sqrt((Omega_m0 / a) + (Omega_lambda0 * a**2) + 1),

# Function to solve Friedmann Equation
def solve_friedmann(Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    a_values = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 1000)
    a_output = []
    for a in a_values:
        result, _ = quad(integrand, 0, a, args=(Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0))
        a_output.append(result)
    return a_values, np.sqrt(a_output) * H0

# Define Omega_M0 and Omega_Lambda0 pairs
Omega_M0_values = [0.3, 0.5, 0.7]
Omega_Lambda0_values = [0.7, 0.5, 0.3]

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for Omega_M0 in Omega_M0_values:
    for Omega_Lambda0 in Omega_Lambda0_values:
     a_values, H_values = solve_friedmann(Omega_M0, Omega_Lambda0)
        plt.plot(a_values, H_values, label=f"Ω_M0={Omega_M0}, Ω_Λ0={Omega_Lambda0}")
plt.xlabel('H_0(t-t_0)')
plt.ylabel('a')
plt.title('Scale Factor Evolution for Different Ω_M0 and Ω_Λ0')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)                                                     
plt.show()

I tried taking out the args part of the code that did not work. I'm suppose to get a graph of the scale factor for different Omega_M,0 and Omega_Lambda,0.

Can you abstract your problem into something with nothing to do with the code? it seems like it might be about quad but I'm not sure. Reading documentation is a good habit

I'm not sure what you are asking for. Since my problem is a coding problem. I provided the error message I got when running the code, my code, and the purpose of my code.

Your problem is related to the call to quad, take what you're giving that and give a smaller dummy example that just works, also check if there's any documentation for it, what you gave is a ton of code and I'm not wanting to put in the effort for it right now. I'd guess that reading the documentation might fix this on it's own but if not I'll give it a look

integrand function get three argemments from quad function and return tuple and you need real number + you need 'a' variable in integrand.
this should work:
i dont know if 'a' is refer the same variable.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import integrate

# Constants
H0 = 70.0  # Hubble constant in km/s/Mpc
Omega_r0 = 0.0  # Radiation density parameter (ignored)

# Function to integrate
def integrand(_, a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    return 1.0 / np.sqrt((Omega_m0 / a) + (Omega_lambda0 * a**2) + 1)

# Function to solve Friedmann Equation
def solve_friedmann(Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0):
    a_values = np.linspace(0.01, 10, 1000)
    a_output = []
    for a in a_values:
        result = quad(integrand, 0, a, args=(a, Omega_m0, Omega_lambda0))
        a_output.append(result)
    return a_values, np.sqrt(a_output) * H0

# Define Omega_M0 and Omega_Lambda0 pairs
Omega_M0_values = [0.3, 0.5, 0.7]
Omega_Lambda0_values = [0.7, 0.5, 0.3]

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for Omega_M0 in Omega_M0_values:
    for Omega_Lambda0 in Omega_Lambda0_values:
        a_values, H_values = solve_friedmann(Omega_M0, Omega_Lambda0)
        plt.plot(a_values, H_values, label=f"Ω_M0={Omega_M0}, Ω_Λ0={Omega_Lambda0}")
plt.xlabel('H_0(t-t_0)')
plt.ylabel('a')
plt.title('Scale Factor Evolution for Different Ω_M0 and Ω_Λ0')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

